# Is there a way to speed up reading the data?

Tags: .net, postgresql, sqldatareader, npgsql, data-retrieval

In the program I created the following logic for reading the data from the database and storing it into List<>:

```
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
                List<UserInfo> result = new List<UserInfo>();
                Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string userId = rdr[0].ToString();
                    string sex = rdr[1].ToString();
                    string strDateBirth = rdr[2].ToString();
                    string zip = rdr[3].ToString();

                    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
                    userInfo.Msisdn = userId;
                    userInfo.Gender = sex;
                    try
                    {
                        userInfo.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateBirth);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                    userInfo.ZipCode = zip;
                    userInfo.DemographicsKnown = true;
                    userInfo.AgeGroup = getAgeGroup(strDateBirth);
                    if (result.Count(x => x.Id== userId) == 0)
                        result.Add(userInfo);
                }
```

The performance of this code is really poor. There are over 2M of records and after half an hour the list userInfo contains just 300.000 records.

Does anyone know how to speed up data reading from the database?

Comment: I noticed you accepted my answer. What were the results after the change?

Comment: Here is the copy from the log file: 20:48:00 Starting with data retrieval from postgres..., 11.6.2012 20:50:42 retrieved 50000 records from postgres

Comment: Ok, so 50,000 records in 3 minutes... a nice improvement on your previous rate of 300,000 records in 30 minutes.... a 60% increase... This still seems very slow, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `.Count` when you really mean `.Any()` 
Whenever you call `.Count` you are enumerating the entire collection just to see if you have a single match....

Consider the question you're asking:
"How many rows do you have that match this condition? Is that number equal to zero?"

What you really mean is: 
"Do any rows match this condition?"

In that context, you could create a Hashset of the userId values. Checking for the existence in a Hashset (or dictionary) can be much faster than checking the same in a list.

Furthermore, if you **do** already have the userId, then you parsed and read all the values for no reason. Check for `myHashset.Contains(userId)` first, then add.

**This is the primary reason it's slow. For n rows you're performing the nth-triangular enumerations of the collection!**

**EDIT:** Consider this untested change: I don't know if your reader supports typed read methods like `GetString()` so if it doesn't then simply use what you had before.

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
List<UserInfo> result = new List<UserInfo>();
Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
HashSet<string> userHash = new HashSet<string>(); // is this actually an int?

while (rdr.Read())
{
    string userId = rdr.GetString(0);
    If (!userHash.Contains(userId))
    {
        string strDateBirth = rdrGetString(2);
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
        userInfo.Msisdn = userId;
        userInfo.Gender = rdr.GetString(1);
        datetime parseddate; // this is not used if the parse fails
        if (Datetime.TryParse(strDateBirth, out parseddate))
        {
            userInfo.BirthDate = parseddate;
            // userInfo.AgeGroup = getAgeGroup(strDateBirth); // why take the string?
            // rewrite your getAgeGroup method to take the datetime
            userInfo.AgeGroup = getAgeGroup(parseddate);
        }
        userInfo.ZipCode = rdr.GetString(3);
        userInfo.DemographicsKnown = true;
        result.Add(userInfo);
        userHash.Add(userId);
    }
}
```

This will always keep the **first** instance of a user row you find (which is what your current code does). If you want to keep the **last** instance then you can use a dictionary and eliminate the `.Contains()` call altogether.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that my sample never added the userId to the hash... whoops... added it in there.

Comment: I'd emphasize the `HashSet` part over the `Any` vs `Count` part here. While `Any` would be better than `Count`, it's still O(n^2) if duplicate users are sufficiently rare. Edit: Another solution might be to just make the query `DISTINCT ON (userId)`.

Comment: @FunctorSalad I completely agree, I only brought it up to illustrate the question he is asking of his `IEnumerable`... furthermore if there are *no* duplicate users then `.Any` and `.Count` are the same... I just think your code should reflect what you mean. He means `Any`, not `Count`

Comment: Just a FYI, `datetime parseddate = null` will bomb as DateTime is not nullable (I ran in to this myself before) you will need to use `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain good point, or I can simply remove the assignment entirely... because if it doesn't parse then it is not used.... I edited my sample

Answer (score 2):

All of that execption handling is slowing down your program a LOT. Exceptions are for ***Exceptional Cases*** If your code is throwing more than 10 execptions you need to re-think your design.

Instead of throwing a execption every time there is a malformed date use [`DateTime.TryParse(string, DateTime)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) instead. It will speed up your code a lot.

```
////Replace This
//try
//{
//    userInfo.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateBirth);
//}
//catch (Exception ex)
//{
//}

//With this
DateTime bithDate;
if(DateTime.TryParse(strDateBirth, out bithDate)
{
    userInfo.BirthDate = bithDate;
}
```

---

Also what is the datatype of the column at `rdr[2]`? Is it already a DateTime? Another thing to do is stop calling ToString on objects everywhere and use the correct methods.

```
while(rdr.Read())
{
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
    userInfo.Msisdn = rdr.GetString(0);
    userInfo.Gender = rdr.GetString(1);

    DateTime? birthdate = null; //This is a nullable DateTime see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

    if(rdr.IsDbNull() == false)
    {
        birthdate = rdr.GetDateTime(2);
        userInfo.BirthDate = birthdate.Value;
    }
    userInfo.ZipCode = rdr.GetString(3);
    userInfo.DemographicsKnown = true;
    userInfo.AgeGroup = getAgeGroup(birthdate); //You may need to edit getAgeGroup to take in a nullable DateTime

    if (result.Any(x => x.Id== userId)) //Any is much faster than count for your check, see Matthew PK's answer.
        result.Add(userInfo);
}
```

Comment: This is a good point but I wonder why bother to parse it at all... If it's not a valid `DATE` then simply return `NULL` from the sproc, then load in the `NULL` into the object (which is what it appears he's doing anyhow!) Datareaders have **typed** reader methods, forget about writing your own `TryParse` implementations.

Comment: @MatthewPK Yea, refresh the screen, I put a big longer part showing how to use the typed methods. However if is date is being stored as a string in the database he will still need to convert it (if he can not do the cast in the select query)

Comment: but that's not what he has now... if the date isn't formatted correctly then he leaves the object property set to its default value.... no reason to make it nullable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to speed up getting data from database you may want to consider different way of reading data instead of looping through reader.

```
DataSet my_dataset = new DataSet();
NpgsqlDataAdapter my_dataadapter = default(NpgsqlDataAdapter);

NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
my_dataadapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
my_dataadapter.Fill(my_dataset, "mydataset");
```

Then do whatever with dataset.
You may be very surprised with difference in speed.